# How to update MySQL query with multiple where and set using or clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause, sql-like

```
Update table 
set col = replace(col, 'value1','') where col like '%value1%'
or set col = replace(col, 'value2','') where col like '%value2%' 
or set col = replace(col, 'value3','') where col like'%value3%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
update table set col = case
    when col like '%value1%' then replace(col, 'value1', '')
    when col like '%value2%' then replace(col, 'value2', '')
    when col like '%value3%' then replace(col, 'value3', '')
    else col
end
```

You could also phrase this query as follows - this is *almost* equivalent to the above query, excepted if `col` contains, for example, both `'value1'` and `'value2'` (in which case both would be replace, while the first query would replace `'col1'`):

```
update table set col =
    replace(
        replace(
            replace(col, 'value1', ''),
            'value2', ''
        ),
        'value3', ''
    )
```

Also, you might want to *filter* the dataset before updating it, especially if your table has a large number of rows. You can do this by adding a `where` clause to the query:

```
where col like '%value1%' or col like '%value2%' or col like '%value3%'
```

Comment: I want if value1 then case 1 should only work and if value 2 comes then only case 2. I could use case but then I am not able to use 'or'

Comment: @rohinisharma: that's what `case` does; it stops at the first matching conditions, applies the corresponding action, and skips the following ones.